# Mongodb only works when I sudo it

Tags: mongodb

When I try to launch MongoDB using `mongod`, it return to me the following message:

```
2017-03-09T20:54:48.868-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9556 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=kallel-Aspire-ES1-511
2017-03-09T20:54:48.868-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-03-09T20:54:48.869-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

How can I solve it, i don't want to sudo it everytime.

Comment: `Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db`  ::  ensure that the user running mongodb has permission to write to the lock directory, either by changing permissions, or by changing configuration to use a different location.

Comment: how do change the permissions? changing the location is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the service (mongod) using root or sudo. Such as:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

But then, without needing root, connect using the mongo client

```
mongo
```